# MonoTouch.Dialog: How to access parent DialogViewController from within Element? Difference between Tapped event and Selected() method?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm subclassing a `StringElement` in `MonoTouch.Dialog`.
In there I can attach to the `Tapped` event or I can override `Selected()`.
Both fire if I tap the element.
However, `Selected()` is giving me access to the `DialogViewController` the element is a member of, where this information is not passed to the `Tapped` event.

What is the logic here? Is an element supposed to know its `DialogViewController` or not? If yes: how to get tho the controller from the `Tapped` event then?

Answer (score 1):

Found out myself by looking at the source on Github.
The only place where `Tapped` event is triggered, is from `Selected()`. So I think Tapped should really by of type `EventHandler` instead of Action.

```
public override void Selected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (Tapped != null)
        Tapped ();
    tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time I wrote that code, the idea was simply that with lambdas, you can pass whatever state you need to your Tapped handler, without using the object/EventArgs pattern.

So you would do something like:

```
var dialogViewController = CreateDvC ();
new StringElement ("....", () => { 
    // reference any variables here
    // my container is:
    Console.Writeline (dialogViewController); 
}
```